# How to get documents solely on the basis of term frequency?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field `comment` in an index. I have three documents with value of field `comment` as:

```
world and hello
hello world
world world world
```

I want to get the documents sorted on the basis of frequency of words. So, if I input `world hello` the output should be:

```
    world world world
    hello world
    world and hello
```

`world world world` has frequency 3(3*world)
`hello world` has frequency 2(1*hello + 1*world)
`world and hello` has frequency 2(1*world+ 1*hello)

I have tried doing this using below query:

```css
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [ {          
        "match" : {
          "comment" : {
            "query": "hello world", 
            "boost":10.0
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this is giving me output:

```
    hello world
    world world world
    world and hello
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, elastic [relevance scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) is just more complicated than you think.

For example when i simulate your example i get different results, this can be due to numerous reasons mentioned in the docs like field length, term frequency and more.

In your case a wordaround is possible using [custom scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-score-query.html) although this will require finding the term frequency for each word and will make the query a little more complex.